# How to programmatically set a permanent environment variable in Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, environment-variables, bash

I am writing a little install script for some software. All it does is unpack a target tar, and then i want to permanently set some environment variables - principally the location of the unpacked libs and updating $PATH. Do I need to programmatically edit the `.bashrc` file, adding the appropriate entries to the end for example, or is there another way? What's standard practice?

**Edit:** The package includes a number of run scripts (20+) that all use these named environment variables, so I need to set them somehow (the variable names have been chosen such that a collision is extremely unlikely)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

LSB-compliant (see [spec](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/etc.html)) practice is to create a shell script in  `/etc/profile.d/` folder.

Name it after your application (and make sure that the name is unique), make sure that the name ends with `.sh` (you might want to add scripts for other shells as well) and `export` the variables you need in the script.  All `*.sh` scripts from that directory are read at user login--the same time `/etc/profile` is `source`d.

Note that this is not enforced by `bash`; rather, it's an agreement of sorts.

Comment: ok this looks like it might be the solution. presumably the installer will need to be run as root in order to write an executable script here.

Comment: Are this script read also by services? For example apache or tomcat?

Answer (score 3):

Standard practice is to install into directories already in the path and in the standard library directory, so there is no need to update these variables.

Updating .bashrc is a bit failure-prone, among other things; what if a user uses a different file or shell?

Comment: +1 correct. Users would be very unhappy if you tried to edit their .bashrc for them. If you want to install into a non-standard directory - or don't think your user will have the permission to - let them specify `--install-dir=mydir` and tell them what they'd need to add to their environment. There is a good example at http://golang.org/doc/install.html

Comment: yes, i thought that editing .bashrc would be dubious for a number of reasons. The problem is the software contains a number of scripts (20+) that all use these named environment variables - so i need to set them somehow.

Comment: One way is to source them in a wrapper script that calls your scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can also generate and install a script that sets those variables. Users of your package then source that script or copy its contents to their own shell init file.

Comment: Or a wrapper script calls the var-setting script at a known name and place and then calls the initial executable.