# Setting environment variables with puppet

Tags: ruby, deployment, environment-variables, environment, puppet

I'm trying to work out the best way to set some environment variables with puppet.

I could use exec and just do `export VAR=blah`.  However, that would only last for the current session. I also thought about just adding it onto the end of a file such as bashrc. However then I don't think there is a reliable method to check if it is all ready there; so it would end up getting added with every run of puppet.

Comment: Isn't 'setting a variable' another way of saying 'edit a rc file'? So you really want to deploy content in a file?

Comment: It is also possible to define system wide environment variables by creating /etc/environment file with KEY=VALUE list of variables.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891972/how-to-programatically-set-a-permanent-environment-variable-in-linux/2892026#2892026).

`*.sh` scripts in `/etc/profile.d` are read at user-login time (as the post says, at the same time `/etc/profile` is sourced)

Variables `export`-ed in any script placed in `/etc/profile.d` will therefore be available to your users.

You can then use a [`file`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.1.latest/type.html#file) resource to ensure this action is [idempotent](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/introduction.html). For example:

```
file { "/etc/profile.d/my_test.sh":
  content => 'export MYVAR="123"'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or an alternate means to an indempotent result:

**Example**

```
if [[ ! grep PINTO_HOME /root/.bashrc | wc -l > 0 ]] ; then
        echo "export PINTO_HOME=/opt/local/pinto" >> /root/.bashrc ;
fi
```

This option permits this environmental variable to be set when the presence of the 
pinto application makes it warrented rather than having to compose a user's 
`.bash_profile` regardless of what applications may wind up on the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you add it to your bashrc you can check that it's in the ENV hash by doing

```
ENV[VAR]
```

Which will return => "blah"

Comment: Thanks, and how would I tell puppet to only run the command if it isn't within the ENV hash?

Comment: It should be ENV['VAR'] to access the environment variable VAR

Comment: `unless ENV[VAR];`
        `puts "This is your code";`
`end;`

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [Github's Boxen](http://boxen.github.com) they source a script (/opt/boxen/env.sh) from ~/.profile. This script runs a bunch of stuff including:

```
for f in $BOXEN_HOME/env.d/*.sh ; do
  if [ -f $f ] ; then
    source $f
  fi
done
```

These scripts, in turn, set environment variables for their respective modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the variables to affect all users /etc/profile.d is the way to go.

However, if you want them for a specific user, something like .bashrc makes more sense.

In response to "I don't think there is a reliable method to check if it is all ready there; so it would end up getting added with every run of puppet," there is now a file_line resource available from the [puppetlabs stdlib module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#file_line):

"Ensures that a given line is contained within a file. The implementation matches the full line, including whitespace at the beginning and end. If the line is not contained in the given file, Puppet appends the line to the end of the file to ensure the desired state. Multiple resources can be declared to manage multiple lines in the same file."

Example:

```
file_line { 'sudo_rule':
  path => '/etc/sudoers',
  line => '%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL',
}

file_line { 'sudo_rule_nopw':
  path => '/etc/sudoers',
  line => '%sudonopw ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL',
}
```