# Puppet manifest to export variables

Tags: variables, path, redis, vagrant, puppet

How can i write a Puppet manifest for exporting 2 variables:

```
export REDISTOGO_URL=redis://192.168.3.4:6379
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/appname/vendor/bundle/bin/
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: You can quote the first one, for example.

Comment: Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: `export REDISTOGO_URL="redis://192.168.3.4:6379"`

Comment: My question was, how to write a Puppet manifest to export those variables in Vagrant machine ?

Comment: Your question was not formulated like that. See that it was confusing (at least to me), so I suggest you to edit your post reformulating it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are utilizing a linux platform, you can use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440972/setting-environment-variables-with-puppet):

The answer to that question suggests using a puppet file resource on an /etc/profile.d script:

```
file { "/etc/profile.d/my_test.sh"
  content => "
export REDISTOGO_URL=redis://192.168.3.4:6379
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vagrant/appname/vendor/bundle/bin/
"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, if i add those line to puppet manifest, i get this errors:
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
Command 'curl' is available in '/usr/bin/curl'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
curl: command not found

~$ echo $PATH
:/home/vagrant/appname/vendor/bundle/bin/

all other env variables are remove from PATH.

Comment: any other suggestion ?

Comment: Escape the `$` or use single quotes.